# What does getIntent() returns at first main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to communicate between `MainActivity` and `BroacastReceviever`.

When a message comes, In `MainActivity`, there should be animation at icon. So when I got a message, I made it to open main activity. But I couldn't handle the animation.

There is my Main activity code below:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Toast.makeText(this, "wow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(intent.getStringExtra("receive").equals("success"))
    InitBadge();
```

There is my broadcast on receive method code below:

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) 
{
    Intent newintent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    newintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //  newintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    newintent.putExtra("receive", "success");

    //  newintent
    context.startActivity(newintent);    
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Will InitBadge() not be executed or something else?

Answer (score -1):

"You can write such as"

```
Intent newintent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
newintent.putExtra("receive","success")
startActivity(newintent);


`String messa=getIntent().getStringExtra("receive").toString()
if(messa.equals("success"){
}`
```